In Pixel 7 facing issue like cropping video with exoplayer when opening initially in portrait
In Android Jetpack Compose when using Exoplayer when an app is defaulted in portrait the time of opening the media player shows media with cropping. But the issue was resolved after switching to LANDSCAPE and switching back to portrait.
The issue will be fixed when the Android view is not set to fillmaxsize. but I need to show it in fillmaxsize because need the controller on the bottom side.
I have tried with AspectRatioFrameLayout and also tried to invoke switchToLandscape() in the time of initialization and back to portrait.
